# PowerShell ComboBox selects one value. Cannot be changed afterwards

Tags: powershell

thank you for helping me out...again^^
As you can maybe see, i want to give the user the possibility to switch the language.
My problem is, that the dropdown always selects `DE`, even if i click on `EN`. And iI have absolutely no clue, why this happens. And sorry, that I cant post the whole code, but it would be 300 lines of Windows Forms Code xD

```
        #ChangeEvent DropDownMenu
        $combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged=
        {
            if($combobox1.Text = "DE")
            {
                $Label1.Text = "Willkommen zur TimeStamp Installation"
                $Label2.Text = ("Um fortzufahren bitte " + '"' + "Weiter" + '"' + " drücken")
                $Label3.Text = ("Zum Abbrechen " + '"' + "Abbrechen" + '"' + " drücken")
                $Label4.Text = "Sprache"
                $Label5.Text = "Wähle dein Programm"
                $groupBox1.Text = 'Programme'
                $radioButton1.Text = 'TimesStamp'
                $radioButton2.Text = 'TimeStamp mit Berichtsheft'
                $Label6.Text = "Installationspfad"
                $Label7.Text = "Wähle den gewünschten Installationspfad"
                $windowButton1.Text = "Durchsuchen..."
                $Label8.Text = "Ein paar Extras"
                $Label9.Text = "Fast fertig."
                $checkbox1.Text = "Erstelle eine Verknüpfung auf dem Desktop"
                $windowButton2.Text = "Weiter"
                $windowButton3.Text = "Weiter"
                $windowButton4.Text = "Weiter"
                $windowButton6.Text = "Fertig"
                $windowButton5.Text = "Abbrechen"
            }
            else
            {
                $Label1.Text = "Welcome to the TimeStamp Installation Setup"
                $Label2.Text = ("To Continue the Installation please press " + '"' + "Continue" + '"')
                $Label3.Text = ("Else press " + '"' + "Exit" + '"' + " to cancel the installation")
                $Label4.Text = "Language"
                $Label5.Text = "Choose your Program"
                $groupBox1.Text = 'Programs'
                $radioButton1.Text = 'TimesStamp'
                $radioButton2.Text = 'TimeStamp with Report booklet'
                $Label6.Text = "Setup Install Location"
                $Label7.Text = "Choose the Folder where the Installation should take place"
                $windowButton1.Text = "Browse..."
                $Label8.Text = "Some Extras"
                $Label9.Text = "Almost finished."
                $checkbox1.Text = "Create Shortcut on Desktop"
                $windowButton2.Text = "Continue"
                $windowButton3.Text = "Continue"
                $windowButton4.Text = "Continue"
                $windowButton6.Text = "Finish"
                $windowButton5.Text = "Exit"
            }

            $window.Refresh()
            $combobox1.Refresh()
        }

        #Actual DropDownMenu
        $combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
        $combobox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(470,30)
        $combobox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
        $combobox1.Height = 80
        $combobox1.Items.Add("EN")
        $combobox1.Items.Add("DE")

        #Activate Event
        $combobox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged)
```

Comment: Your issue is most likely here `if($combobox1.Text = "DE")` it should be `if($combobox1.Text -eq "DE")`

Comment: Ahhh I did it again....I always keep typing `=` instead of `-eq`. Why?! xD
But anyways thanks it worked^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Owain Esau` said:

Your issue is most likely here `if($combobox1.Text = "DE")` it should be `if($combobox1.Text -eq "DE")`